# Convert Latin characters to Normal text in Java

Tags: java

I have the following characters.

Ą¢¥ŚŠŞŤŹŽŻąľśšşťźžżÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ

I need to convert to

AcYSSSTZZZalssstzzzAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYTSaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyty

I am using Java 1.4.

Normalizer.decompose(text, true, 0).replaceAll(
                "\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", ""); only replaces characters with diacritics.

Characters like ¢¥ÆÐÞßæðøþ is not getting converted.

How can I do that, what is the efficient way to do the conversion in JDK 1.4.

Please help.

Regards,
Sridevi

Comment: Y isn't really an equivalent for ¥ - considering ¥ means "Yuan". You will probably have to implement a lookup table as @stephen-c suggested

Comment: I need help to form the lookup table and get the equivalent characters from the lookup table. I may not want the look up table to contain ¥, i may want to store the unicode equivalent and convert the same to some Y.

Comment: Agree with @Deco and just to add to the topic, I don't think ß is equivalent to S either... At least in German it is equivalent to SS, replacing printing "Straße" as "Strase" and not "Strasse" would just be wrong.

Comment: I dont understand you editor thing: any today IDE is UTF-8 by default and can display all these chars (just as my brother is doing).

Comment: Neither first line contains latin characters nor are those from the second line normal. What is your definition of normality? What is Latin language for you?

Comment: Ą¢¥ŚŠŞŤŹŽŻąľśšşťźžżÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ -these characters falls within Basic Latin, Latin supplement , Latin extended . Now the ascii equivalent fro this is AcYSSSTZZZalssstzzzAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYTSaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyty. It is fine to have Y for ¥.

Answer (score 7):

Check out the [ICU project](http://site.icu-project.org/), especially the icu4j part.
The `Transliterator` class will solve your problem.

Here is an example a `Transliterator` that converts any script to latin chars and removes any accents and non-ascii chars:

```
Transliterator accentsConverter = Transliterator.getInstance("Any-Latin; NFD; [:M:] Remove; NFC; [^\\p{ASCII}] Remove");
```

The `Any-Latin` part performs the conversion, `NFD; [:M:] Remove; NFC` removes the accents and `[^\\p{ASCII}] Remove` removes any non-ascii chars remaining.

You just call `accentsConverter.transliterate(yourString)` to get the results.

You can read more about how to build the transformation ID (the parameter of `Transliterator.getInstance`) in the [ICU Transformations guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general).

Comment: but i want to do a conversion example ¥ means Y.

Comment: Like @Deco mentioned in a comment, ¥ to Y is not the correct conversion. However, for these special needs, you can create a mapping of the conversions you expect, and then first to those, then pass it to ICU.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I do that, what is the efficient way to do the conversion in JDK 1.4.

The most efficient way is to use a lookup table implemented as either an array or a `HashMap`.  But, of course, you need to populate the table.

> Characters like ¢¥ÆÐÞßæðøþ is not getting converted.

Well none of those characters is really a Roman letter and can't be translated to a Roman letter ... without taking outrageous liberties with the semantics.  For example:

- ¢ and ¥ are currency symbols,
- Æ and æ are ligatures that in some languages represent two letters, and in others are a distinct letter,
- ß is the german representation for a double-s.

Comment: How should the lookup table look like? I do not want to save the look up table with the special characters as some editors will not support those, can I place the equivalent unicode charactes in the look up, if yes how the code should be? I have to get the unicode character from the lookup table and how will I convert it in to the normal text?

Comment: I would have thought a `char[]` would be more efficient than a HashMap. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey - it depends on the size of the input set, and whether you are optimizing for space or time.

Comment: On Java 1.4, you have to create a Character for every input char. For a short input you might be better off not building a HashMap and just using two String with indexOf

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this;

UPDATED FOR Java 1.4 (removed generics)

```
public class StringConverter {

    char[] source = new char[]{'Ą', '¢', '¥', 'Ś'}; // all your chars here...
    char[] target = new char[]{'A', 'c', 'Y', 'S'}; // all your chars here...
    //Build a map
    HashMap map;

    public StringConverter() {
        map = new HashMap();
        for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
            map.put(new Character(source[i]), new Character(target[i]));
        }
    }

    public String convert(String s) {
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            chars[i] = map.get(chars[i]);
        }
        return new String(chars);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am using JDK 1.4 and I dont want to store the special characters as eclipse supports by default CP1252 encoding.

Comment: What is the connection between Eclipse's default encoding and the Java version? You can change the default encoding in Eclipse to UTF-8 and it should still work.

Comment: Thanks. I have mentioned Java 1.4 for HashMap<Character, Character> map.

Comment: I would use a `char[]` as the "map" data structure.

Comment: Sorin is right, there are no relationship between the Encoding of your source code inside the IDE and the default Encoding for converting char to byte[] (by default the Encoding of your computer Local).