# How to convert latin alphabet to english counterpart in java?

Tags: java

I saw several solutions for removing diacritics using normalizer, but none to convert latin alphabet (such as Œ,Æ,Ø,ß) to its english counterpart.

Comment: Does this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188575/convert-latin-characters-to-normal-text-in-java

Comment: A nit: removing diacritics is not "converting to English". English has diacritics. An a-e ligature, æ, is perfectly good English; it appears in the name Cæsar, which is the "good typography" way to write Caesar.  Similarly, an o with diaresis is used in words like "coöperate".

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a library to do this it might be something you can do yourself or you can just create mappings in Map and use that. I think it would be the simplest way.

Comment: Yes that was the only solution. Didn't find third party library to handle ligatures. I just created my own class that replaces the ligature with its corresponding english alphabets.